# How to skip listitem with index 0 foreach checkboxlist item

Tags: c#, foreach, checkboxlist, listitem

I have a `CheckBoxList` which I am going through all its items using:

`foreach (ListItem item in this.checklist.Items)`

I was wondering how I can skip the first item in this `CheckBoxList`(item with index 0).

Comment: Can we see your current code?

Comment: Use a for loop instead of a foreach and set your starting index to 1. A foreach iterates over the entire collection. If you want control over what it processes and what it doesn't based upon the index you use a for loop.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Linq should help you do the trick. Make sure to cast the items collection to typed collection, and then you can use `Skip` to skip first item:

```
foreach (ListItem item in this.checklist.Items.Cast<ListItem>().Skip(1))
```

Comment: That is a neat solution

Comment: This is a great answer. What if the first item does not have the index of 0 or 1? I mean what if I do not know what is the index for the first item and just want to skip the first one?

Comment: A class object wasn't provided, so it's correct that index is the physical position in the list, so the answer still correct.

Answer (score 0):

I believe one way to do this is:

```
bool isFirst = true;

foreach (ListItem item in this.checklist.Items)
{ 
    if (isFirst) {
        isFirst = false;
    }  else {
    // do checking
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this.

```
foreach (ListItem item in this.checklist.Items)
{ 
    if (item != this.checklist.Items[0]) {
        // Do something
    }
}
```